# Is Heroku overriding my 500 error message?

Tags: http, heroku, httpresponse

I'm trying to return a custom error message from http 500 responses. When testing it locally it provides the custom response, but when running on Heroku it gives a generic "Internal Server Error" response. Does Heroku override 500 error responses? And if so, is there a way to have it use the custom one I sent?

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload your custom error messages and maintenance pages to an external source such as S3 for example. You then need to add to your apps config the location of your error pages so they can be called when needed.

```
heroku config:add \
  ERROR_PAGE_URL=http://s3.amazonaws.com/your_bucket/your_error_page.html \
  MAINTENANCE_PAGE_URL=http://s3.amazonaws.com/your_bucket/your_maintenance_page.html
```

See the Heroku docs for more info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages